# Ignite Client Node Never Ends

Tags: ignite

While trying to start an Ignite Node as a client i.e "ClientMode=True" in absence of any ServerNode running, The process logs the below message on the console and just keeps on running and never ends [image: message]

As per the message,the process goes under a retry and waits for a server node to join, which I believe is a default behavior! But is there a way to set a timeout for waiting or max retry count ? as I don't want my process to wait for more than 10 sec.

Below is the configuration that I am using to start an ignite client.

```
`IgniteConfiguration
            {
                Localhost = "127.0.0.1",
                ClientMode = true,
                AutoGenerateIgniteInstanceName = true,                
                DiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi
                {                    
                    LocalPort = 48500,                    
                    LocalPortRange = 2,
                    IpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder
                    {                     
                        Endpoints = new[] { "127.0.0.1:48500..48501" }
                    }
                },               
                CommunicationSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi
                {
                    LocalPort = 48100
                }               
            });`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set timeout, during which the node will have to connect to a cluster in [TcpDiscoverySpi#joinTimeout](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/TcpDiscoverySpi.html#setJoinTimeout-long-). If this timeout exceeds, then the node will stop trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the reconnect delay using:

https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/TcpDiscoverySpi.html#setReconnectDelay-int-